# angular8 output decorator is not working giving the error

Tags: angular

demo.Parent.html

```
<p>demo-parent works!</p>
<app-demo-child (property)="parentFunction($event)"  ></app-demo-child>
```

demo.parent.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo-child',
  templateUrl: './demo-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo-child.component.css']
})
export class DemoChildComponent implements OnInit {



@Output() property = new EventEmitter<string>();

 value : string="angualr";

  constructor() { 

  }


  senndData(){
    this.property.emit( this.value);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

demo.child.html

```
<p>demo-child works!</p>
```

demo.child.component.ts

```
export class DemoChildComponent implements OnInit {

@Output() property = new EventEmitter<String>();

 value : string="angualr";

  constructor() { 

  }


  senndData(){
    this.property.emit( this.value);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

.

what is an error in this? as I am new to angular I was learning the output decorator. I am unable to revive the data from the child component and show it in the parent component

Comment: error is related to coffee script not output decorater

Comment: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1 WARNING in ./node_modules/protractor/built/configParser.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'coffee-script' in '/home/sangamnath/Desktop/angualr/ball/node_modules/protractor/built'

Comment: i guess demo.child.component.ts and demo.parent.component.ts file look same can you please check once

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, You need to change / send data in the child, when doing some event in the parent.

If so, this is a simple demo how you can modify the child when the parent element is clicked for example.

First, we need a trigger in the parent component, we'll use (click) event.

**demo.Parent.html**

```
<p>this is the parent component </p>
<button (click)=sendData()> click me to change the child value </button>
```

Now let's implement the sendData() function in the demo-parent.ts class in order to emit the evet

**demo.parent.component.ts**

```
export class DemoParentComponent implements OnInit {

 @Output() property = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }

  senndData(){
    this.property.emit("new value from parent");
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

as you can see, when clicking at the botton, we trigged a function which emits the output to the child

Now let's welcome our recieved data in the child component :

**demo.child.html**

```
<app-demo-parent(property)="parentFunction($event)"></app-demo-parent>
```

Finally, we'll need a function to be called in the child component, when the parent is clicked, in this case it is parentFunction()

**demo.child.component.ts**

```
export class DemoChildComponent implements OnInit {

 value : string="angualr";

   constructor() { 
   }

 parentFunction(valueFromParent : string){
  this.value = valueFromParent;
  console.log("You have recieved a new value from the parent : valueFromParent ");
 }

  ngOnInit() {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As looking at your error
in parent.component.ts file you just need

```
parentFunction(childValue : string) {
   console.log('value form child' + childValue );
}
```

you are receiving error because i think in `parentFunction` was not taking any argument jut make sure that your `parentFunction` has one argument
For more details - https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular